# Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 1 (terratest CI fetching module from terraform cloud)

Tags: github-actions, terraform-cloud

[Getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtnDl.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtnDl.png]

I have all the necessary tokens included in the yaml.
The code ran with no issues before.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the issue persists considering there were an [outage on GitHub side (regarding Codespace)](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/7rghmvv5crq0), while there was [no recent incident on Terraform Cloud](https://status.hashicorp.com/history).

The first one might have an incidence on accessing the second one.